# Drop all tables from database in single query in mysql

Tags: mysql

Yes i have searched for this but got solution for this in single query.

Any solution in `MySQL` to `drop all tables`(**NOT TRUNCATE**) from database **in single query**.

Comment: Why not dropping the database (all permissions are kept separately) ?

Comment: `drop database ur_dbname` ?

Comment: you are right but just for knowledge any solution over this.Not any intention as such

Comment: dropping a database also drops all stored procedures defined. OP only wants to drop tables;

Comment: Alternatively, If you are using PhpMyAdmin or Adminer, just click on the database name, then click on "select all" or top checkbox in the list of tables and hit "Drop", unless you have 100's of tables, this should be easy enough.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

As far as I know you have to do it individually:
DROP TABLE user, settings, images